# Problem with blank screen after using react-context

Tags: react-native, themes, expo, react-context

I'm trying to make a dynamic themes but i have got a problem. When im using React.context with Provider and Consumer my app does not display anything on the screen.

It's my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Route from './route/Route';
import { ThemeProvider } from './reusables/theme/themeContext';

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Route);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <AppContainer/>   
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

-- route

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const BaseStack = createStackNavigator(
{
    Overview: { 
      screen: OverviewScreen,
      navigationOptions: { header: null, },
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Overview',
    }
})
export default BaseStack;
```

-- provider class

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
    themeColor: '#f45',
    changeThemeColor: () => null,    
});

export const ThemeConsumer = ThemeContext.Consumer;

export class ThemeProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        themeColor: '#f45',
    }

    changeThemeColor = (themeColor) => {
        this.setState({ themeColor });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider 
                value={{
                    themeColor: this.state.themeColor,
                    changeThemeColor: this.changeThemeColor,
                }}>
                { this.props.children }
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

-- child component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StatusBar, ScrollView, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';

/* --- STYLES - COLORS ---*/
import gStyle from '../styles/Style.global';
import { ThemeConsumer } from '../reusables/theme/themeContext';

export default class OverviewScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeConsumer>
                {( themeColor ) => {
                    <View style={[{backgroundColor: themeColor}, gStyle.container]}>
                        <StatusBar hidden/>
                        {this.overviewPage()}
                    </View>
            }}
        </ThemeConsumer>
    );
}
```

When i try to run app screen is blank. There is no warrning in console. I'm at a loss for how fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your props aren't being passed to the AppContainer:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider>
        <AppContainer {...this.props} />   
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work. Still blank screen like the child component could not render.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the Context.Consumer

Edit: Better late than never.